# Cascading Listboxes. Select First Item in sub list automatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using MVVM in a WPF project. My View has 2 list boxes on it. The second ListBox is bound to the SelectedItem of the first. Similar to having a province/state ComboBox get filled when you select a country, only using ListBox instead.

The part I am having trouble with is getting the second ListBox to select the first item in it when the user selects a new item in the first box.

Ideally I'm looking for some XAML way of doing this, but am open to throwing something in the code behind if need be.

My objects are represented in my view model like so:

```
    public ObservableCollection<TrafficSignal> TrafficSignals
    {
        get { return _trafficSignals; }
        set
        {
            _trafficSignals = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TrafficSignals");
        }
    }

    public TrafficSignal SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

Same ojbects in my model:

```
public class TrafficSignal
{
    public string DataTag { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public List<Timing> Timings { get; set; }
}
public class Timing
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<TimingPhase> TimingPhases { get; set; }
}
public class TimingPhase
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Finally here are the relevant parts of the View:

```
<StackPanel>
        <Label>Master List</Label>
        <ListBox Name="listTimings" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Timings}"
        ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource timingsListTemplate}"
        SelectedIndex="0"
        />

        <ListBox Name="listPhases" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listTimings, Path=SelectedItem.TimingPhases}"
        ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource phasesListTemplate}"
        SelectedIndex="0" 
        />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I do something like this, but I actually implement MVVM.  Your VM should have a `SelectedTiming`, `SelectedTimingPhase`.  When the `SelectedTiming` is set to !null, you can call `SelectedTimingPhase = _selectedTiming.TimingPhases.First()`.  This also means that you should have a TimingPhases observable collection.  When the SelectedTiming changes to !null, you clear the ObservableCollection TimingPhases, then repopulate it using _selectedTiming.TimingPhases.  Is this making sense?  I can write the VM as an answer if needed.

Comment: I would make a handler for the DataContextChanged event and set the selected index to 0.

Comment: I would not do that ^

Comment: @NETscape That makes sense I'll try it and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `TargetUpdated` event handler and select the first item there like this:

```
 <ListBox Name="listPhases" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listTimings, Path=SelectedItem.TimingPhases, 
            NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
    ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource phasesListTemplate}"
    TargetUpdated="OnTargetUpdated"
    SelectedIndex="0" 
    />

void OnTargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
    if (lb != null && lb.HasItems) 
    {
        lb.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

[See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.notifyontargetupdated(v=vs.100).aspx) for a description of the event.